# Can't debug Watir scripts running under watir-classic (3.4.0)

Tags: watir, rubymine, ruby-debug

I am developing Ruby scripts under Watir 4.0.2 so that I can test Internet Explorer under Watir-classic, and
other browsers (e.g., FireFox) under Webdriver.

If I set the environment variable 'WATIR_DRIVER=webdriver' I can breakpoint/debug my code (using
either IE or FireFox) using the RubyMine 5.0 debugger (with ruby-debug-base19x, ruby-debug-ide). 
However, when I set 'WATIR_DRIVER=classic' (to test using IE) the debugger process terminates my 
session prematurely with the following message:

Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta16, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11.30.pre11) listens on 127.0.0.1:51303
....
Process finished with exit code -1073741819

I am running under Windows 7, IE 9 with a current Ruby environment:

- Rubymine 5.0 (RM-125.52)
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
- *** LOCAL GEMS ***
- debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.7)
- ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre11, 0.11.30.pre10)
- ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta16, 0.4.17.beta14)
- selenium-client (1.2.18)
- selenium-webdriver (2.29.0, 2.27.0)
- watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
- watir-classic (3.4.0)
- watir-webdriver (0.6.2, 0.6.1)

Does anywone have any idea what may be happening here?

Could the problem be with the ruby-debug-* gems?

Are there other options to reliably debug Watir scripts under watir-classic?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions.

Bob Barnhart, SAIC

Comment: You will probably get better answers in rubymine support forum.

Comment: I went to RubyMine support first and they had no idea. Since then I tried debugging the same code in the same environment using Aptana and got the same failure. At this point I'm pretty sure the problem is actually in the ruby-debug-base19x gem. Perhaps there is a better forum to direct that inquiry?

Comment: Can you debug it from the command line, e.g. insert a statement where you want to have your breakpoint at ````require "ruby-debug"; debugger````? If yes, then the problem is probably in the remote debug approach.